# EVM instruction to transfer value from one account to another

Tags: go-ethereum

When a normal transfer is done (not contracts) from one account (non-contract) to another (non-contract) , is the EVM executed? If so, what is the instruction code that is being run in the EVM at the time of transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In geth the transfer is done outside of the EVM.

The function that executes a transaction is `Call` in [go-ethereum\core\vm\evm.go around line 138](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/32516c768ec09e2a71cab5983d2c8b8ae5d92fc7/core/vm/evm.go#L138)

It first execute the transfer in [line 166](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/32516c768ec09e2a71cab5983d2c8b8ae5d92fc7/core/vm/evm.go#L166)

```
 evm.Transfer(evm.StateDB, caller.Address(), to.Address(), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

"An Ethereum client handles the cryptographic signing process and broadcasts a request for the transaction to be executed on the EVM when an externally-owned account initiates a transaction. A validator node then executes the transaction and sends the EVM state change as a result of this transaction to the rest of the network."

Paraphrased from [this page](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/) on the Ethereum Docs